# LMER: Why do non-reference group individuals' random intercepts average to the reference group's intercept mean in LMER?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, fixed-effects-model

First time using LMER. Really appreciate any help!
For df to illustrate my questions, I alter ToothGrowth as follows:

```r
data("ToothGrowth")
ToothGrowth$len <- sort(ToothGrowth$len)
day <- rep(c(1:10), times=6)
id <- rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), each=10)
df <- data.frame(cbind(ToothGrowth$len, as.character(ToothGrowth$supp), 
                                        day, id))
colnames(df) <- c("Length", "Treatment", "Day", "ID")
class(df) <- c("numeric", "factor", "numeric", "factor")
df$Length <- as.numeric(df$Length)
df$Treatment <- factor(df$Treatment, levels = c("VC", "OJ"), order = FALSE)
df$Day <- as.numeric(df$Day)
df$ID <- factor(df$ID, levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), order = FALSE)
```

**My LMER:**

```r
model1 <- lmer(Length ~ Day * Treatment + (1 | ID ), data = df, 
              REML = FALSE)

#to look at fixed effects
fixef <- unlist(fixef(model1))

#to look at random intercepts
random_intercepts <- print(coef(model1)$ID[,1])
```

**My definitions:**

1. `fixedef[1]` is the reference group (OJ) intercept
2. `fixedef[2]` is the reference group (OJ) slope?
3. `fixedef[3]` is the difference between OJ intercept and VC intercept?
4. `fixedef[4]` is the difference between OJ slope and VC slope

**Question:**
If my definitions are correct, then why do VC random intercepts `random_intercepts[1:3]` average to the reference group (OJ) intercept? Should I add `fixedef[3]` to `random_intercepts[1:3]` for accurate random intercepts for non-reference group individuals?

I've reviewed tons of LMER posts but none asking such a basic question are using exactly my model structure and I'm not sure how their output *should* differ in order to interpret their results/and their received answers.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in Section 1.1 of the [`lmer` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf).

The random effects are assumed to be "multivariate normal with mean zero"; with a simple random intercept as in your example, that's just a zero-mean Gaussian distribution with a variance to be estimated from the data. Equation 2 of the vignette shows (absent offset terms) that the fixed-effect coefficients are those in place when the random-effect values are at their mean values of 0.

The confusion comes from how the random intercepts are modeled. You can think of the random intercepts as hypothetical differences from the overall intercept *if all cases received the `OJ` treatment*: that is, after correction of those receiving the `VC` treatment for the fixed `VC-OJ` treatment difference. That type of hypothetical estimate is common  in regression modeling. In your example, the intercept is the estimated outcome for the `OJ` treatment at `Day=0`, a value for `Day` that isn't in the data set.

You could "correct" the random intercepts of the cases with the `VC` treatment to represent their estimated intercepts given their `VC` treatment. But even then, you are estimating an intercept that's a hypothetical estimate at (the non-existent) `Day=0` for those cases. I'd recommend just thinking about the random intercepts as hypothetical values for cases all corrected back to the same baseline conditions. Then use software tools to make predictions as needed for various hypothesized values of fixed predictors and random effects.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! To clarify: your second paragraph makes me think I might have been partially misunderstood to be asking about reference/non-reference group identity in regards to the random effects term (`ID`). I meant `Treatment`, with `df$Treatment=="OJ"` being the reference group, and `df$Treatment=="VC"` being the non-reference group. But if my fixed-effect coefficient definitions above are incorrect, what would be the correct definitions of `fixef[1:4]` in the above code? Really needing to understand the LMER output specifically if you're able to help!

Comment: @ghost_pants I might have misinterpreted your question, as you suggest. I will edit the answer in a while.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, I now fully understand and all my questions were answered!